# How to insert to custom identity table instead of ASPNetUser table in ASP.NET Core using Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I need to insert to `customidentity` table instead of `ASPNetUser` table.

`Customidentity` table got created. But while user registration it gets inserted into the `AspNetUser` table. How to solve this issue?

This is my `AccountController`:

```
using InventoryManagement.Models;
using InventoryManagement.Models.ViewModel;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace InventoryManagement.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserManager<CustomIdentity> userManager;
        public SignInManager<CustomIdentity> Signinmanager { get; }

        public AccountController(UserManager<CustomIdentity> userManager, SignInManager<CustomIdentity> signinmanager)
        {
            this.userManager = userManager;
            Signinmanager = signinmanager;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost] 
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel registerviewmodel) 
        {
            var identityuser = new CustomIdentity
            {
                UserName = registerviewmodel.Username,
                Email = registerviewmodel.Email,
                IsEngineer = registerviewmodel.IsEngineer ?? "N",
                authpassword = registerviewmodel.authpassword
            };

            var identityresult = await userManager.CreateAsync(identityuser, registerviewmodel.Password);

            if (identityresult.Succeeded)
            {
               // assign user a userrole 
               var roleIdentityResult= await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(identityuser, "User");

               if (roleIdentityResult.Succeeded) 
               {
                   return RedirectToAction("Register");
               }
            }

            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel loginviewmodel)
        {
            var signinresult=   await Signinmanager.PasswordSignInAsync(loginviewmodel.Username , loginviewmodel.Password, false, false);

            if (signinresult != null && signinresult.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("index", "Home");
            }

            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
        {
            await Signinmanager.SignOutAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult AccessDenied()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my `Customidentity` model class:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace InventoryManagement.Models
{
    public class CustomIdentity : IdentityUser
    {
        public string  IsEngineer { get; set; }
        public string  authpassword { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have provided the `customidentity` model and the controller. User registration function is inserting data into `ASPNetUser` table instead of custom identity. `Customidentity` table is properly created after migration, but value is not getting inserted.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create another table instead of "ASPNetUser" table. The additional field could be added to the default "ASPNetUser"table with following settings

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<Customidentity>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<Customidentity>
{
...
}
```

[image]

If you want to change the table name ,you could modify dbcontext like

```
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<Customidentity>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
              //necessary before change table name.
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Customidentity>().ToTable("CustomIdentity");
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: customidentity table is automatically  created . my customidentity model is  exactly same as you suggested .now the problem is that my job table is referring customidentity table and customidentity table has no data. data resides in ASPNETUSER table

Comment: @LakshmiSureshan  It should have create only 1 table for user. May I see your dbcontext how do you create them?

Comment: this is my code here is my AuthDbcontext.cs file using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity; using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore; using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore; namespace InventoryManagement.Models.Data { public class AuthDbContext : IdentityDbContext<CustomIdentity> { public AuthDbContext(DbContextOptions<AuthDbContext> options) :base(options) { }}} @Qiang Fu

Comment: This is my Job table reference to identity ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Jobs]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Jobs_CustomIdentity_UserId] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[CustomIdentity] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE